# Looking for Pricegrabber.com API

Tags: api

I saw many e-commerce sites using Pricegrabber for price comparison.

For example:
http://www.cheapstingybargains.com/184212/lg-gp08lu10-8x-dvd%C2%B1rw-dl-usb-20-slim-external-drive-w-lightscribe/

Is there a pricegrabber API for developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/pricegrabber), pricegrabber does have an API but to even see its documentation you have to negotiate with the site itself.  If that's not acceptable to you, the page I'm pointing to has pointers to many other shopping sites with APIs that may be more suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/pricegrabber), the PriceGrabber API is no longer available.